# WordPress Main and Meta icons are swapped

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

When selecting a site, the icon for WordPress Development is gray, but the icon for WordPress Development Meta is red.

iOS app:

[image: Screenshot of site selector in iOS app]

Dropdown:

[image]

Site:

[image]

Isn't that the reverse of the UI convention that Meta sites have desaturated colors?

Comment: Same in the dropdown.

Comment: And the site as well...

Comment: This belongs on the Wordpress Meta, not the SE Meta. Also, it looks intentional. The colors on the main site are monochromatic and on the Meta, the red is more used.

Comment: @Catija Sorry, I posted here because I had originally thought that it was a problem with the [tag:ios-app].

Comment: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/401/new-design-launched This seems to show that the icons are **intentionally** the way they are.

Comment: @Catija It's not intentional, as evidenced by the icons linked from the post you cited: http://sstatic.net/wordpress/img/favicon.ico and http://sstatic.net/wordpressmeta/img/favicon.ico

Comment: Um... the meta one is black and red and the regular one is white and black... at least, that's how they look to me... As far as I can tell, that confirms that what you're seeing is the correct icon usage.

Comment: Actually, what they look like depends on the browser I'm using. Chrome has them with the red W as Main site and grey W as Meta. FF shows them reversed with the red W having a black background in addition to the red letter.

Comment: @Catija Reporting here is fine enough, especially since the bug report is for the iOS app.

Comment: @AnnaLear I'm not arguing that it shouldn't be here, actually asking: Is it about the iOS app, though? The OP noticed it first in the iOS app, true, but I'm not using the iOS app and am seeing the same behavior. Seems like a bigger problem than just on the iOS platform.

Comment: @Catija Hmm. It... might not actually be a bug at all. I'll check with the design team tomorrow. It's common for meta to be grayscale and the for the main site to be in color, but it's not *required* as such.

Comment: I agree, the bug seems not about the iOS app, unless it's bigger than that, or it's by-design. I'm using Chrome, and meta.wp shows red-on-black, while main WP shows black-on-white, contradicting the meta post about design update on WP.